# ReactJS - How do I validate input fields

Tags: reactjs, required, requiredfieldvalidator, required-field

I'm using reactstrap components.
there is more than one input.
how do I set some fields to "required".
that is, the user cannot pass idle. how can such restrictions be made?

```
<Row>
   <Col xs="2">customer name</Col>
   <Col xs="6">
        <Input
        required
        maxLength={"20"}
        type={"text"}
        placeholder={"customer name"}
        name={"customerName"}
        defaultValue={this.state.customerName}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
   </Col>
</Row>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try this one: https://availity.github.io/availity-reactstrap-validation/ ? Does a pretty good job.

Sorry to write here, but it seems at don't have enough reputation to answer.

availity-reactstrap-validation extends the reactstrap forms with some nice functions like validation.

In order to have labels on left and inputs on right you can mix them like this:

```
<AvForm onValidSubmit={handleValidSubmit} onInvalidSubmit={handleInvalidSubmit}>
        <FormGroup row>
            <Label for="name" sm={2}>Name</Label>
            <Col sm={10}>
                <AvField name="name"  type="text" required />
            </Col>
        </FormGroup>

    </AvForm>
```

Be sure that you have imported all the libraries.

Comment: I'm trying now,

Comment: I will use it, but how can I make the label on the left and the input on the right

Comment: Pretty easy man, here is my quick example, i have it in a component: return (
        <AvForm onValidSubmit={handleValidSubmit} onInvalidSubmit={handleInvalidSubmit}>
            <AvField name="name" label="name" type="text" required />
            <Button color="primary">Add name</Button>
        </AvForm>
    ) and the output is: <div class="form-group"><label for="name" class="">name</label><input name="name" required="" id="name" type="text" class="is-untouched is-pristine av-invalid form-control" value=""></div> - pretty basic bootstrap.

Comment: hey man, i got what you asked for, check my initial answers, i have update it.